# How is the complex functional derivative defined?

Tags: reference-request, definition, inner-products, functional-calculus

Let $\overline{A}$ be conjugation, $A^T$ be transposition and $A^H$ be conjugation and transposition. Given the usual $L^2(\mathbb{C})$ inner product:

$$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx$$

and the energy ($f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}), A,B : L^2(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{C})$, $A,B$ linear):

$$E[f] = \langle \mathcal{A}f, \mathcal{B}f\rangle,$$

If $f$ is real I take the functional derivative using the definition:

$$\left\langle\frac{dE}{df},\phi\right\rangle = \frac{d}{d\lambda}E[f+\lambda\phi]|_{\lambda=0}=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\langle A(f+\lambda\phi), B(f+\lambda \phi)\rangle|_{\lambda=0} = \\
\langle Af, B\phi\rangle + \langle A\phi, Bf\rangle = \langle B^HAf, \phi\rangle + \langle \overline{Bf}, \overline{A\phi}\rangle = \langle B^HAf, \phi\rangle + \langle A^T\overline{Bf}, \overline{\phi}\rangle= \langle (B^HA+A^T\overline{B})f, \phi\rangle,$$

then $\frac{dE}{df} = (B^HA+A^T\overline{B})f$. First of all, is this derivative correct? I think I have some mistake since I expected to get something symmetric from it, e.g. $(B^HA+A^HB)f$. Also how  would the functional derivative for a complex $f$ be defined. Would I stop at the point:

$$\left\langle\frac{dE}{df},\phi\right\rangle = \langle B^HAf, \phi\rangle + \langle A^T\overline{Bf}, \overline{\phi}\rangle,$$

and then term $\frac{dE}{df}=B^HAf$ and $\frac{dE}{d\overline{f}} = A^T\overline{Bf}$? Or would I split up the imaginary and real terms and then have $\phi_R, \phi_I$ for those and take derivatives with respect to those? References are more than welcome.

Comment: I didn't check in details, but it looks ok to me. The dependence of both $E$ and $dE/df$ on $(A,B)$ is sesquilinear.

Comment: @IvoTerek Do you know any reference that discusses the case of a complex $f$ and $\phi$? Would it ever make sense to mix and match a real $f$ and a complex $\phi$? This sounds a bit strange to me since it is like taking a complex directional derivative an using this to define $\frac{dE}{df}$. Would the $\frac{dE}{df}$ defined using a complex $\phi$ and the one using a real $\phi$ agree?